# Spark SQL cannot access Spark Thrift Server

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, spark-thriftserver

I cannot configure Spark SQL so that I could access Hive Table in Spark Thrift Server (without using JDBC, but natively from Spark)

I use single configuration file `conf/hive-site.xml` for both Spark Thrift Server and Spark SQL. I have `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` property set to `jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/home/user/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/metastore_db;create=true`. I also set `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` property to absolute path pointing to `spark-warehouse` directory. I run Thrift server with `./start-thriftserver.sh` and I can observe that embedded Derby database is being created with `metastore_db` directory. I can connect with `beeline`, create a table and see `spark-warehouse` directory created with subdirectory for table. So at this stage it's fine.

I launch pyspark shell with Hive support enabled `./bin/pyspark --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive`, and try to access the Hive table with:

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hc = HiveContext(sc)
hc.sql('show tables')
```

I got errors like:

> ERROR XJ040: Failed to start database
>   '/home/user/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/metastore_db' with class loader
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1b4fb997
>
> ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the
>   database /home/user/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/metastore_db
>
> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;

Apparently Spark is trying to create new Derby database instead of using Metastore I put in config file. If I stop Thrift Server and run only spark, everything is fine. How could I fix it?

Is Embedded Derby Metastore Database fine to have both Thrift Server and Spark access one Hive or I need to use e.g. MySQL? I don't have a cluster and do everything locally.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded Derby Metastore Database is fine to be used in local, but for production environment, it is recommended to use any other Metastore database.
Yes, you can definitely use MYSQL as metastore. For this, you have to make an entry in `hive-site.xml`.

You can follow the configuration guide at [Use MySQL for the Hive Metastore](https://mapr.com/docs/51/Hive/UsingMySQLfortheHiveMetas_29655346-d3e108.html) for the exact details.

Comment: Why is embedded derby bad in production? Who recommends against it? Thanks.

Comment: Quote: "But the default embedded deployment mode is not recommended for production use due to the limitation of only one active SparkSession at a time. "